# ls command - list files containing a specific string in file name and belong to specific type

Tags: find, ls, wildcards

Is it possible for an `ls` command to return a list of files containing "PRO" in its file name and belong to pli file type?
I have researched and identified that `ls -c -lt *.PLI` will return a files of ".pli" type and `ls -c -lt *PRO*` will return file which has PRO in its file name.

Example:
If the folder contains:

- aaaaaPROaaaaa.PLI
- aaaaaPROaaaaa.PSO
- aaaaaPROaaaaa.txt
- bbbbbPRObb.PLI
- bbbbbPRObb.txt

... then I need the `ls` command to return only *`aaaaaPROaaaaa.PLI and bbbbbPRObb.PLI`*

If it is not achievable through the `ls` command, can we achieve it through the `find` command?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With `ls`, you can do:

```
ls -c -ltd -- *PRO*.PLI
```

With `find`:

```
find . ! -name . -prune -type f -name '*PRO*.PLI'
```

(note that `find` will include hidden files like `.xPRO.PLI` while the shell glob (`*PRO*.PLI`) will not by default).

Comment: Gnouc: It is so simple.. I thought it will be more complex :-).
Thanks a lot for your quick solution.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why prune everything rather than `-maxdepth 1`?

Comment: `prune` is defined by POSIX, `-maxdepth 1` not.